# SQL queries for calculating users who visited at once every week and every week

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a usage table with user_id and login time. I want to get the number of users who logged in at least once a day. I also need to get the number of users who logged in at least once a week.

Any idea how can I go about it with a redshift query?

Here is the schema:

**user_id: BigInt

event_time: Datetime**

Example results:

**No. of users who logged in at least once every day: 20
No. of users who logged in at least once week: 5**

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Give the structure of your schema in the question

Comment: user_id is BigInt and event_time is a Datetime field.

Comment: What did you try so far? Use generate_series() to create a list of dates, from your start to the end, and join on this list.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake, this is redshift. generate_series is not fully supported on redshift. I have no idea how to go about this, I tried a few grouping on user_id and DATE(event_time) and haven't got anything positive.

Comment: what about event_type? will it be all the events same (Login)? Not Logout?

Comment: All the events are same, i.e. "login"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* Days range from date1 to date2 */
WITH day_range AS (
  SELECT current_date + i AS day
  FROM generate_series(DATE [$from_date] - current_date, DATE [$to_date] - current_date) i
)

/* Users logged at least once a day */
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM user_event
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT user_id 
   FROM day_range LEFT JOIN user_event ON day_range.day = user_event.event_time::date
   WHERE user_id IS NULL)
```

For users who has been logged at least once a week it should be more complicated but something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo SQL, should give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
            WHEN daycount = datediff('day', '{start_date}', '{end_date}')
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS visited_every_day
    ,Sum(CASE 
            WHEN weekcount = datediff('week', '{start_date}', '{end_date}')
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS visited_every_week
FROM (
    SELECT user_id
        ,Count(DISTINCT to_char(event_time, 'YYYYMMDD')) AS daycount
        ,Count(DISTINCT to_char(event_time, 'WW')) AS weekcount
    FROM user_event ue
    WHERE Event_time BETWEEN '{start_date}'
            AND '{end_date}'
    GROUP BY user_id
    ) stage
```